# Checking if path is a socket in Python 2.7

Tags: python, file, sockets, types, path

What would be the best way in Python 2.7 to find out if a path is a socket?

[os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) has *is...* functions for [directories](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir), [normal files](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) and [links](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink). The [stat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html) module offers some S_IS... functions like [S_ISSOCK(mode)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISSOCK) which I used as

```
import os, stat

path = "/path/to/socket"
mode = os.stat(path).st_mode
isSocket = stat.S_ISSOCK(mode)

print "%s is socket: %s" % (path, isSocket)
```

Is this the prefered way?

Comment: I don't see any other way. It seems reasonable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, this is straight forward and works, so I take this as the canonical way.